# Process Creation Time from Process Memory (Win32)

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I have to retrieve a process creation time from PID of a certain process. I believe (not sure)windows saves the process start time somewhere in process memory(User Mode). Is it possible to read it directly from memory??

I know windbg has an option (.time) which does the same, But I want to know is it possible to get it manually using windbg or any other debugger??

Thanks in Adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use wmic from command prompt CreationDate  will list the Creation Time of All Running Process

```
time:\>wmic process get processid , name , creationdate | grep opera
20140616162551  opera.exe               1108

time:\>tlist 1108 | grep Stack
1108 opera.exe         windows - Process Creation Time from Process Memory (Win3
2) - Stack Overflow - Opera

time:\>
```

if grep is not preferable use findstr.exe an inbox utility in windows

```
time:\>wmic process get processid,creationdate,name | findstr /C:opera
20140616162551  opera.exe               1108
```

if you want to get it from windbg make a script file and run a local kd session from command prompt as shown below (/debug switch reqd in os vista+ )

```
C:\>type printtimes.txt
aS ${/v:ctime}  @@( ( ( nt!_EPROCESS * ) @#Process )->CreateTime.QuadPart ) ;
aS ${/v:pid}    @@( ( ( nt!_EPROCESS * ) @#Process )->UniqueProcessId ) ;
aS ${/v:imname} @@( ( ( nt!_EPROCESS * ) @#Process )->ImageFileName ) ;
.block { !for_each_process ".printf \"%20ma\t%8d\t\",${imname},${pid};!filetime
${ctime}" }
q
C:\>kd -kl -c "$$>a< c:\\printtimes.txt" | findstr /c:opera
           opera.exe        1108         6/16/2014 16:25:51.500 (unknown)
```

and GetProcessTimes is implemented like this

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void printtimes(FILETIME *ft);
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) { printf ("usage proctime.exe Pid\n"); return 0;}
    HANDLE      hProc = NULL;
    FILETIME    ft[4];
    memset(&ft,0,sizeof(ft));
    if ( ( hProc =  OpenProcess( 
        PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, 
        FALSE, strtoul( argv[1], NULL, 10 ) ) ) != NULL )
    {
        __asm
        {
            push 0                  // retn value ignored
                push 20h            // sizeof input buffer 
                lea eax,ft  
                push eax            // inputbuffer
                push 4              // processinfoclass
                push hProc          // Handle to Process
                lea ecx,retback  
                push ecx            // setup stack and index for sysenter
                mov eax, 09ah       // index of NtQueryInformationProcess
                mov edx,07ffe0300h  // sysenter in winxp sp3
                call [edx]          // kuser KiFastSystemCall pointer
            retn 14h                
        }
retback:
        printtimes(&ft[0]);
        CloseHandle(hProc);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Could not open process quitting\n ");
    }
    return 0;
}
void printtimes(FILETIME *ft)
{
    SYSTEMTIME  stime,ltime; 
    memset (&stime,0,sizeof(stime));
    memset (&ltime,0,sizeof(stime));
    FileTimeToSystemTime(ft,&stime);
    SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(NULL,&stime,&ltime);
    printf(
        "%02d-%02d-%04d %02d:%02d:%02d\n",
        ltime.wDay,ltime.wMonth,ltime.wYear,
        ltime.wHour,ltime.wMinute,ltime.wSecond);
}
```

result

```
time:\>proctimenew.exe
usage proctime.exe Pid

time:\>proctimenew.exe 1108
16-06-2014 16:25:51

time:\>
```

Comment: Thanks...This is useful as well..But we cant use grep on windows..we need to use find.. :)

Comment: grep is available for windows from gnuwin32 if you dont prefer grep use findstr an inbox utility in windows

Comment: cool..thnx..BTW i use this one wmic process get processid , name ,creationdate | find "iexplore"

Comment: @DavidA. This is not manually and not using a debugger. How can this become the accepted answer? Please update your question so that finally it is at least clear what you want.

Answer (score 4):

This information is stored in a kernel mode object:

```
0:077> dt nt!_EPROCESS
ntdll!_EPROCESS
   +0x000 Pcb              : _KPROCESS
   +0x06c ProcessLock      : _EX_PUSH_LOCK
   +0x070 CreateTime       : _LARGE_INTEGER
   +0x078 ExitTime         : _LARGE_INTEGER
   ...
```

So the only way to get this information at runtime is via an API call to [GetProcessTimes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as already stated by Raymond Chen or [Process.StartTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.starttime) in .NET (probably uses the API call internally).

To get the information manually in the debugger, you would need a pointer to a _EPROCESS structure and then use `dt nt!_EPROCESS <address>`. You can get the addresses from a kernel dump using `!process 0 7 myapp.exe`.

Comment: Thanks for the info..I really appreciate..It seems it can't be done using user land debugger..Will give it a try this weekend by reversing GetProcessTimes!Kernel32 , and see how it works..

Comment: GetProcessTimes calls ZwQueryInformtionProcess with Processinfo class 4

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use the [GetProcessTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223.aspx). This takes a handle to the process, which you can retrieve from the indicated PID with [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx). Something like the following should produce similar results to .time.

```
void Process(_TCHAR* szPid)
{
_TCHAR* pEnd;
DWORD pid = ::_tcstoul(szPid, &pEnd, 10);

HANDLE handle = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, pid);

if (handle == NULL)
{
           // Error handling omitted.
}
else
{
    FILETIME createTime, exitTime, kernelTime, userTime;

    if (!GetProcessTimes(handle, &createTime, &exitTime, &kernelTime, &userTime))
    {
                    // Error handling omitted.
    }
    else
    {
        OutputToConsole(L"Process Uptime", &createTime);
        OutputToConsole(L"  Kernel time", &kernelTime);
        OutputToConsole(L"  User time", &userTime);
    }

    ::CloseHandle(handle);
}
}

 void OutputToConsole(TCHAR* descr, const FILETIME* lpFileTime)
 {
SYSTEMTIME stDiff = FileTimeDiff(lpFileTime);
_tprintf(TEXT("%s: %hu days %hu:%02hu:%02hu.%03hu\n"), descr, stDiff.wDay, stDiff.wHour, stDiff.wMinute, stDiff.wSecond, stDiff.wMilliseconds);
 }

 SYSTEMTIME FileTimeDiff(const FILETIME* ftDT)
 {
SYSTEMTIME stNow;
::GetSystemTime(&stNow);
FILETIME ftNow;
::SystemTimeToFileTime(&stNow, &ftNow);

ULARGE_INTEGER uliNow, uliCurrent, uliDiff;
uliNow.LowPart = ftNow.dwLowDateTime;
uliNow.HighPart = ftNow.dwHighDateTime;

uliCurrent.LowPart = ftDT->dwLowDateTime;
uliCurrent.HighPart = ftDT->dwHighDateTime;

uliDiff.QuadPart = uliNow.QuadPart - uliCurrent.QuadPart;
FILETIME ftDiff;
ftDiff.dwLowDateTime = uliDiff.LowPart;
ftDiff.dwHighDateTime = uliDiff.HighPart;

SYSTEMTIME stDiff;
::FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftDiff, &stDiff);

return stDiff;
 }
```

The result of this on one of my process is following:

```
Process Uptime: 8 days 7:18:42.303
  Kernel time: 16 days 7:06:31.995
  User time: 16 days 7:11:16.462
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation..I really appreciate..But this is not actually what i am looking for.. :(